# Objects for xib

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

When my xcode load I see such panel of elements:

[image]

But when I click on any file in project this panel disapear and apper this panel:

[image]

After that I can't open extended version of elements no way to add them in xib file. How can I open it?

Comment: If you're developing for iOS, these "extended" elements aren't relevant. They're for Mac OS development.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about it

Comment: You're welcome. Posted as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a huge difference between the object library available for Cocoa and for Cocoa Touch. The "extended" elements you speak of are only available for OSX development.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the elements you talk about are for Mac-Development (Cocoa) only and aren't appropriate for or even supported by iOS (UIKit / Cocoa Touch)

these controls don't conform to IOS HIG and aren't implemented by the frameworks